# In Dragon Fantasy, how do you find the healer?

Tags: dragon-fantasy

Once you go to the castle you started at (castle Wester), and see the Queen (Queen Becca), she asks you to bring a healer. I have seen no healer anywhere, I've searched in all the caves and everywhere and every town I can find on the map and have found no healer. I went back and nothing has changed. I'm not allowed to go anywhere else, and I've spent several hours in game looking for this (incidentally gaining many levels) and not found a healer anywhere. Would someone please tell me where to find a healer, our how to heal them yourself maybe? I really am completely lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took many hours and I explored every last inch of the map. Then the towns. The last town I looked, the last corner. :)

In the second town (the one where anders and soldier searched), top left corner is a healer's house. Check a note, and it tells you of a cave. Find that cave in the top left corner of the main map. Go in there, to the left are stairs. Don't take those, but go to the right and take those stairs. Take them, and go right, then up, then left.

You'll run into a troll (previously mentioned by healers note) who is weak but gives much exp and money. Kill it. Afterword you say to yourself something like: "The herbs have been picked. I hope the healer made it back ok." Then you go back to the healer's house. YAY!